# Alternative to cron for scheduling job

Tags: cron, scheduling

I need to schedule jobs, but i'm looking for solution which can dispatch task by following rules like: launch one task by rss feed i need to refresh but dispatch it during the day.

I imagine a queue system where i send a list a command to execute and a time period where they need to be dispatch.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying I am a developer for this company so I am a bit biased.  We make a solution called JAMS Job Scheduler which is a job scheduling and batch queue facility.  JAMS allows you to set triggers and dependencies and also has Cron and Task Scheduler converters. You can check it out at www.JAMSScheduler.com

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from Airbnb: chronos

https://mesos.github.io/chronos/

Answer (score 0):

My company makes CloudQuartz ([www.thecloudblocks.com](http://www.thecloudblocks.com)) which allows you to schedule the jobs through an API and get callbacks when they are due to run.